# Redactor.js S3 upload issues

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am using [Redactor.js](http://redactorjs.com/) on a website, specifically the [Amazon S3 image upload function](http://redactorjs.com/docs/examples/s3/). I'm running in to trouble with cross-domain scripting, as Firebug is giving this error:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

I have tested my upload form independently and it uploads fine. Any ideas?

**Edit**: Although the error appeared to be a cross-domain issue, it is actually just failing to parse the server response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the server response: the JSON returned from the server **MUST** be a single line. Any new lines will break the parser.